# how to add cms static block to newsletter subscriber templates

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, static-block, newsletter

I would like to know how I can add static block to newsletter subscriber templates

Answer (score 1):

You can add static block in any template using this code

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-new-block')->toHtml();
```

You first have to create static block
add your block id instead of my-new-block.

Comment: i am using this code code its not working

Comment: Where is your newsletter.phtml is located ?

Comment: {magento root path}/app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/newsletter

Comment: have you confirmed by template path hints ? also clear your cache,.

Comment: wah bhai....improvement ;) @Bhavin

Comment: @Rajan thanks for reply now its working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your newsletter subscribe template file and call static block with following code :

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Newsletter file will be in following path :

**{magento root path}**/app/design/frontend/**{your package}**/**{your theme}**/template/newsletter

Comment: i used your code but it did not work ...

Comment: have you put above code in above path subscribe.phtml file?

Comment: Please check your file path using template path hint then put above code and clear cache because this is working.